# How to find a row in a table using jquery/css/selectors

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with various rows:

```
...
<tr class="selectedrow">
...
            <td>8/5/1987</td>
...
</tr>
...
```

I need to locate a row and assign a class to it:

```
var row = $this.find("tr:class=selectedrow")
{
    row.addClasss("ui-state-default");
}
```

Is there a syntax to make this work ?

Comment: `$(".selectedrow").addClass("ui-state-default");`?

Comment: With what criteria you want to select the row?

Comment: You should learn a bit about CSS selectors before attempting to use them.

Comment: @ZiNNED: You should have posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the selected row having a css class applied to it then selecting that row is trivial:

```
var selectedRow = $('.selectedrow')
```

Adding the css class to it is also simple:

```
selectedRow.addClass('ui-state-default');
```

Answer (score -1):

just like this :

```
var row = $this.find("tr.selectedrow")
```